# Putting data into countdown timer (Android)

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for my game app. The user has to enter a duration while creating the challenge, and the duration will be converted to time and start counting down. So far I created the timer, but kind of stuck with grabbing the duration and converting to time. Thanks for reading and have a nice day!

```
new CountDownTimer(16069000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    tv5.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        tv5.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

this is a normal countdown table w/o grabbing any data. Any examples or mind changing the codes to help out a little? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: In which format does the user enter duration? EditText? Spinner?

Comment: It's in the form of spinner

Comment: Well just get the selected number of the spinner, multiply it with 1000 and pass it instead of **16069000**. I don't get your confusion,